# Thermal printer - disable automatic cutting (only when printing image)

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

I am trying to print a GIF on a thermal printer and then not cut the tape. I found out that it's no problem for me to print Strings as InputStream without the printer cutting.

I found this handy code to print GIFs.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;

import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImagePrint {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;
    SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(new MyPrintable(), flavor, null);
    job.print(doc, null);
  }
}

class MyPrintable implements Printable {
  ImageIcon printImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("a.gif");

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.translate((int) (pf.getImageableX()), (int) (pf.getImageableY()));
    if (pageIndex == 0) {
      double pageWidth = pf.getImageableWidth();
      double pageHeight = pf.getImageableHeight();
      double imageWidth = printImage.getIconWidth();
      double imageHeight = printImage.getIconHeight();
      double scaleX = pageWidth / imageWidth;
      double scaleY = pageHeight / imageHeight;
      double scaleFactor = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
      g2d.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
      g.drawImage(printImage.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
      return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
    return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
  }
}
```

*http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Printanimageout.htm*

That takes my image and prints it - however, something (I have no idea what) causes the printer to activate the cutting and cut the tape off. Since I want images at the beginning of my receipts - this is not what I want.

Somehow I found out if I replace the **NO_SUCH_PAGE** with **PAGE_EXISTS** it just prints the image endlessly - but without cutting. (Yes, I have to turn the printer off and on) However, that tells me it's possible.

My question is, how? Is there anything that could do the job, just something like "print over but don't cut?" Or something like - "this is a tape that shall not be cut?"

Any other advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the printer's docs?

Comment: To be honest - I have Sewoo LK-TL322 and there is NO info about anything.. Terrible company. Good printer. Good price. But 0 docu. But I stronly believe its more a java issue becasue as said I acn print streams without cutting.

Comment: Ok I just took different approach. I took the GIF and converted into InputStream and took the flavor as DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF and ran. IT CUT. That means that the "cutting" caller is somehow hidden in the flavor of the GIF itself? Im getting headache... doh

Comment: Thermal printer work with the ESC commands and there must be a command for cutter as well. You have to get that command and find out when that command is executing. Just get that point and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to set the cutting option in printer settings.

For windows open devices and printer and right click on your printer and select printing preferences and goto tab operation and select end of document and end of page. Then change the paper cut option